# Android studio app crashes, even it's clear

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

My app crashes even tho there is no problems in build phase and no errors in code. It's just an empty app with basically no code in it. It's not run in emulator or right in my mobile as a `.apk` build.

There is example of code, but I don't think it's where is a problem:

```
 package com.example.justdo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int value = 10;
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText_ID);
        myTextView.setText(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the LogCat that describes the exception you are seeing, but [`myTextView.setText(value);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)) is probably not what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it was caused by a misnomer id in the textview.

Sorry and thank's everyone for help.

Answer (score 2):

Textview accepts "String" value only .if you want set integer as text ,you need to use String.valueOf(integer).

```
    int value = 10;
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText_ID);
    myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Comment: Yeah, but there is a same problem, if this line of code doesn't here.

Comment: Add your logcat message with your question .So that i can see what is real pbm.@FilipMarek